# rearranging of linked list elements

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am in new to data structures , exploring it splcially the linked list and in linked i am trying
to achieve the following..

1)Given a linked list, reverse alternate nodes and append at the end

```
  Input List:  1->2->3->4->5->6
  Output List: 1->3->5->6->4->2
```

2)Given a linked list, reverse alternate nodes and append them to end of list. Extra allowed space is O(1)

```
   Input List:  12->14->16->18->20
   Output List: 12->16->20->18->14
```

please advise the logic and how can I implement this in java.Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question title is misleading.. This isn't *shuffling*. You are *rearranging* the elements based on some criteria.

Comment: @TheLostMind potato potato? what is difference?

Comment: @Lostmind... Thanks changed the subject

Comment: @tuntutnsdsds to me they are the same thing

Comment: @KickButtowski - [Collections.shuffle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) is the difference..

Comment: @KickButtowski ok but i am still stuck up for the logic man..!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I shuffle nodes in a linked list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588033/how-do-i-shuffle-nodes-in-a-linked-list)

Comment: @tuntutnsdsds - Are you using the default *LinkedList* implementation or your own custom one?

Comment: @TheLostMind I bet the op has its custom made linked list

Comment: @LostMind ...the default one provided by java

Comment: @tuntutnsdsds - Then, my friend, you are in luck.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go buddy : This is for the first one .. Try similar thing for the second one. Happy coding.. :)

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> l1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    l1.add(1);
    l1.add(2);
    l1.add(3);
    l1.add(4);
    l1.add(5);
    l1.add(6);
    List<Integer> tempList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<l1.size();i=i+2){ // from 0, add alternative elements 0,2,4....
        tempList.add(l1.get(i)); 
    }

    for(int i=l1.size()-1;i>=0;i=i-2){ // from tail of LL add alternative elements n-1,n-3,..0/1
        tempList.add(l1.get(i)); 
    }

    System.out.println(tempList);
}
```

O/P :

[1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2]

Comment: what happened to explantion? at least I have some

Comment: @KickButtowski - added explanation in comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below method

```
public static List<Integer> arrange(List<Integer> input) {

    Integer[] temp = new Integer[input.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
         if(i%2 != 0) {
             temp[input.size() - (i+1)/2] = input.get(i);
        } else {
             temp[i/2] = input.get(i);
        }
    }
    return Arrays.asList(temp);
}
```